# Filtering blocks + adding a class to every 3rd element

Tags: jquery

I'm using [Filtering Blocks](http://css-tricks.com/filtering-blocks-v2/) code written by Chris Coyier, but I want to add a class 'last' to every third 'block' element (to remove margin-right).
So far I have this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="blocks-nav">
     <a rel="all" class="current">All</a>
     <a rel="www">Internet</a>
     <a rel="ci">Logo</a>
</div>

<div id="blocks-gropup">
     <div class="block all www">
     <!-- some content -->
     </div>

     <div class="block all ci">
     <!-- some content -->
     </div>

     <div class="block all www">
     <!-- some content -->
     </div>

     <div class="block all ci">
     <!-- some content -->
     </div>

     <div class="block all ci">
     <!-- some content -->
     </div>

     <div class="block all www">
     <!-- some content -->
     </div>         

</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {

        var newSelection = "";

        $("#blocks-nav a").click(function(){

            $("#blocks-nav").fadeTo(200, 0.10);

                $("#blocks-nav a").removeClass("current");
                $(this).addClass("current");

                newSelection = $(this).attr("rel");

                $("div.block").not("."+newSelection).slideUp();
                $("."+newSelection).slideDown();

            $("#blocks-group").fadeTo(600, 1);

        });

});


$("div#blocks-group > div:nth-child(3n)").addClass('last');
```

This last line actually works, and adds a class "last" to every 3rd div, but after filtering blocks, the class stays with the same div, which isn't necessary at 3rd position.
So, my question is - how can I merge those two functions, so the class would be added on page load to every third div, then removed and added again after filtering blocks.

Any help or assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Slight oversight, filtering entailed hiding the elements, so expression "nth-child(3n)" will simply not work after filtering. Also the code is quite simple to fix, see below:

```
$(function() {

    var newSelection = "";

    $("#blocks-nav a").click(function(){

        $("#blocks-group").fadeTo(200, 0.10);

        $("#blocks-nav a").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");

        newSelection = $(this).attr("rel");

        $("div.block")
            .removeClass("last")
            .not("."+newSelection)
            .slideUp();

        $("div.block."+newSelection)
            .slideDown()
            // unfortunatly, have to use an .each()
            .each(function(i){
                if ( !((i+1) % 3) ) { // every third from result set.
                    $(this).addClass("last")
                }
            });

        $("#blocks-group").fadeTo(600, 1);

    });

    $("#blocks-group > div.block:nth-child(3n)").addClass( "last" );

});
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/d7n8F/3/

Comment: i've tried to implement your solution, but i must be doing something wrong.. it doesn't work :/ this is my code: [link](http://dronka.org/filtering-blocks.js)

Comment: Appologies, new solution. Kept a reference to old invalid solution because I still think the technique is quite dandy.

Comment: Your new solution works great, but not in the way I need it to work. It adds class 'last' only to last element, not every 3rd. Is there any other (other than expression "nth-child(3n)") option to add class to every 3rd element, which would work with filtering/hiding elements?

Comment: Righty oh, updated code again and new jsfiddle link with working example.

Comment: **BGerrissen** you're the best! Thanks a million!